# Where to catch exception from rmw?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some issues about exceptions from "rmw publish" (e.g., https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/issues/317).

Is exception from "rmw publish" a bug and it is not necessary to catch exception in my code? Or my code is responsible for catching exceptions from rmw?

What are ROS2 agreements about exception handling?

I cannot find any ROS2 guides about where exceptions are expected to be catched: in my code (where rclcpp::Publisher::publish called), somewhere in rclcpp or in rmw layer. There are no instructions in ROS2 tutorials about exceptions (https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber/).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362008/where-to-catch-exception-from-rmw?/) by [rrrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/59836/rrrand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rmw` is a C API (not C++) and as such there can be no exceptions raised. If any RMW implementation does raise an exception (which it shouldn't) please fill a ticket in the corresponding repository since that needs to be fixed within the RMW implementation.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2